# What does "Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1" mean

Tags: java, jdbc, entity, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I would like to save two entities with the following relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Synonyme {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private List<Term> terms = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Term {
   private String word;
   public static createTerm(String word, Synonyme newSyn, Long someothercriteria) {
    Term term = new Term();
    ...
    newSyn.addTerm(term);
   }
}
```

And I want to save them like this:

```
Synonyme newSyn= Synonyme.createSynonyme ();

entityManager.persist(newSyn);

for(String word : words) {
    Term term = Term.createTerm(word, newSyn, 0L );
}

 entityManager.flush();
```

These codes work fine in Junit-Test (The Junit-Test uses an in-memory database of spring) but if I use them in the real database I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1
```

I don't understand this exception. What does it mean and what I could do?

Comment: Is there a bidirectional relation between `Synonyme` and `Term`? If so, you need a `mappedBy = "synonyme"` (or similar) in `@OneToMany`.

Comment: @PredragMaric There is no bidirectional relation between Synonyme and Term, but the create methode does something like this: synnonyme.setTerms(terms), so I think if I am trying to save synonyme, the terms will be saved, but the term was created with synonyme.setTerms(). It may be the problem. But I don't know how can I avoid the problem. Do you have some idea? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(too long for comment, so adding an answer)

You should update the question with the code of `Synonyme.createSynonyme()` and `Term.createTerm()`.

Your `@OneToMany` mapping is strange, that could be the cause of the problem (check out the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-collections) for collection mappings). In this `@OneToMany` the target table (Term) contains foreign key to source table (Synonyme). That said, `ID` is probably not the column you want, but something like `SYNONYME_ID`. You can also post your table structure so anyone interested can have the full picture. Once the mapping looks OK, it will be easier to look for the solution to the problem, if it doesn't get resolved when mappings are fixed.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I edited the question just now:) I would analyse our table structure now! Hope it works soon.

Comment: I checked our table structure. You're correct. Our table structure doesn't match the structure of entities. I'm going to change the relationship and I'm sure it will work soon:)

Comment: Good luck, I hope you won't have any more problems with it :)

Comment: Yes, it was the problem! That is also why our junit tests always work fine but not with the real data base! The real data base has another structure than our entity relationships:D Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

That usually means you defined a primary key in hibernate but not on the actual DBMS.

And now there are 2 rows with the same primary key ("actual row count 2, expected 1") so hibernate cannot even perform a simple non-update query (!).

To fix, delete in DBMS the duplicated row or change hibernate key definition on that table.